# How to organize a large number of variables in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

i first want to say that i'm beginner in ocaml. So i made a simple app that takes data from a json, does some calculations or replace some of them with arg from the command line, then writes another json with the new data and also replace those values in a html template and writes that too. You can see my project here https://github.com/ralcr/invoice-cmd/blob/master/invoice.ml

The question is how to deal with that amount of variables? In the languages i know i would probably repeat myself twice, but here are like 6 times. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would like to notice, that [StackExchange code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to post such questions, as the question is more about a design rather than about the language.

I have two suggestions, on how to improve your code. The first one is to use string maps (or hashtables) to store your variables. Another is much more radical, is to rewrite the code in a more functional way.

### Use maps

In your code, you're doing a lot of pouring the same water from one bucket into another, without doing actual work. The first thing that comes to mind, is whether it is necessary at all. When you parse JSON definitions into a set of variables, you do not actually reduce complexity or enforce any particular invariants. Basically, you're confusing data with code. These variables, are actually data that you're processing not a part of the logic of your application. So the first step would be to use string map, and store them in it. Then you can easily process a big set of variables with fold and map.

### Use functions

Another approach is not to store the variables at all and express everything as stateless transformations on JSON data. Your application looks like a JSON processor, so I don't really see any reason why you should first read everything and store it in the memory, and then later produce the result. It is more natural to process data on the fly and express your logic as a set of small transformations. Try to split everything into small functions, so that each individual transformation can be easily understood. Then compose your transformation from smaller parts. This would be a functional style, where the flow of data is explicit.

Comment: In order to use functions i'd need to first load the json, then analyse the args is that right? Luckily i don't need any input to load the json but i don't know what the future will bring, however i'll try. Next step is to update the values directly in the json, then iterate over the placeholders and update the html.

Comment: So i greatly simplified everything by not storing all the variables, i store only the ones from Arg because i don't see another way around this. I plan to do an interactive input for the rest of the vars. Thanks!